# How can I limit the depth of a JSON in Java? (Remove entries that are no longer in the "depth range")

Tags: java, json, gson, limit, depth

Currently I have a JSON that can basically have an "infinite" depth.
Is there any chance I can limit the depth and only get like the first couple levels of the JSON? Maybe even with a Library like Jackson or GSON?

Current JSON could look as following:

```
    "id": "77ec211f-b6d1-46fb-afe8-c799e65db04c",
    "name": "Test",
    "type": "TOP",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "c2ab68a3-dfb2-4002-ae07-826f30d169e3",
            "name": "Austin Fadel",
            "type": "MID",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "cafe8bf0-74a6-476f-99c3-4db584ec47fe",
            "name": "Spring Keebler",
            "type": "MID",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "53ff0d5f-ee7f-4648-a718-c9c3acbf44f4",
            "name": "Jinny Von I",
            "type": "MID",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "092c279a-baaa-4c1a-9656-7ecd5d2f3c97",
                    "name": "Max Power",
                    "type": "LOW",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "0925279a-baaa-4c1a-9656-7ecd5d2f3c97",
                            "name": "Max Lower",
                            "type": "LOW",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        {
            "id": "cd3bbcab-6ef4-459e-8d43-74dbd73c12c5",
            "name": "Jayson Feest",
            "type": "MID",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "092c279a-baaa-4c1a-9656-7ecd5d2f3c97",
                    "name": "Max Power",
                    "type": "LOW",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "0925279a-baaa-4c1a-9656-7ecd5d2f3c97",
                            "name": "Max Lower",
                            "type": "LOW",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2fb8e01c-ffc6-4535-8241-ad057946961a",
            "name": "Gladys Jast",
            "type": "MID",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

thx for any help

Comment: fixed it with a recursive method calling himself with the new "tree" (lower level), the current depth and the max desired depth and then at the very end when it reaches the max desired depth it will just set children to an empty list ;)

Answer (score -2):

This is a pretty general programming problem. You'll get yelled at without some actual code and not just showing us the data, but here are some general thoughts to help you come up with some code, and then post it if you still need help.

Basically you just need to keep track of a `depth` variable. The parent node has a depth of 0 and its children have a depth of 1. When you're traversing the tree keep track of your depth. When you go to a child node, increment depth and when you go to a parent node, decrement it. At each step, check your depth against some `max_depth` variable, and if you're as deep as you wanna go, don't go to any child nodes.

There may be methods that let you do this more easily but you can at least offer some starting code this way that people can offer suggestions on.